# Mongoose can't connect (localhost)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, apollo

I am trying to connect to my database using mongoose within Apollo-Server-Express. I have created a db in the terminal. I read that 'mongodb://localhost:27017/*db-name
*' is the default uri-string that mongoose.connect takes as first argument.

However, `console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)` prints out '2' - connecting.
I would expect '1', right?
When querying, the server freezes, and a *ServerSelectionError* gets thrown.
I have tried prepending the mongoose.connect statement with *await* (as I saw in a tutorial) but then, the start-up process freezes.
Is there anything fundamental that I am missing?
Any help appreciated!!

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const main = async () => {
  const app = express();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
  });

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db-name', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });

  console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);

  console.log('MongoDB connected!!');

  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at port ${process.env.PORT || 4000}`);
  });
};

main();
```

Comment: Is the mongod service running? You might need to open a terminal and run the mongod command.

Comment: and you already confirmed you have mongodb itself running?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments guys!
So the problem was twofold:

1. Mongod was indeed not running. I realized that I had gotten an error-code of 100, which meant that the directory data/db did not exist.
   I first tried out `$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db` but still got the same error.
   What then helped was to create the directory in the root and running mongod with `$ mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`. That got MongoDB running.

But still the same problem with my server...

2. It turned out that in my case the uri should be `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-name`. If I now wrap printing out the server connection status in a setTimeout, I get the expected response of 1 and can do my queries!